# How to use a callable as a filter in logging python

Tags: python-3.x, logging, callable-object

I don't know how to use this [new property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) of python3.2. There, instead of implementing logging.Filter class, one can use a callable.

- I'm trying to use [dictConfig](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/config.py#L484) for my logger (in python). In that, I want to add a filter such that it will pass if record's message contains certain phrase.
- I know how to do that by implementing logging.Filter class.
- But I don't know how to just use callable 'fancy' property of python 3.2 as stated [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L744)

Good code here

```
class ignore_progress(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):

        return not ('Progress' in record.getMessage())
class log_progress(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return ('Progress' in record.getMessage())
def contain_progress(record):
    return not ('Progress' in record.message)
logging_dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,  
    "formatters": {
        "standard": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s",
        }
    },
    "filters": {
         "ignore_progress": {
            '()': ignore_progress,
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "default": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "standard",
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "standard",
            "filename": 'training_{}.log'.format(str(datetime.date.today())),
            "filters": ["ignore_progress"],
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {"handlers": ["default", "file"], "level": "DEBUG", "propagate": True, },
    },
}
# Configurate the logger
logging.config.dictConfig(logging_dict)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info("Run training")
logger.info("Progress.test")
```

Bad code here

```
class ignore_progress(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):

        return not ('Progress' in record.getMessage())
class log_progress(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return ('Progress' in record.getMessage())
def contain_progress(record):
    return not ('Progress' in record.message)
logging_dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,  
    "formatters": {
        "standard": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s",
        }
    },
    "filters": {
         "ignore_progress": {
            '()': contain_progress,
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "default": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "standard",
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "standard",
            "filename": 'training_{}.log'.format(str(datetime.date.today())),
            "filters": ["ignore_progress"],
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {"handlers": ["default", "file"], "level": "DEBUG", "propagate": True, },
    },
}
# Configurate the logger
logging.config.dictConfig(logging_dict)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info("Run training")
logger.info("Progress.test")
```

The above bad code has a problem at this [line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/config.py#L472) in `config.py`

Answer (score 4):

When using Callable in dictConfig, the Callable you put into the value of dictConfig has to be a Callable which returns a Callable as discussed in the Python Bug Tracker:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue41906

E.g.

```py
def my_filter_wrapper():
    # the returned Callable has to accept a single argument (the LogRecord instance passed in this callable) with return value of 1 or 0
    return lambda record: 0 if <your_condition_here> else 1

logging_dict = {
    ...
    'filters': {
         'ignore_progress': {
            '()': my_filter_wrapper,
        }
    },
    ...
```

Or even simpler if your custom filtering logic is a one-liner and independent on the log record instance:

```py
logging_dict = {
    ...
    'filters': {
         'ignore_progress': {
            '()': lambda : lambda _: 0 if <your_condition> else 1
        }
    },
    ...
```

It took me a long while to figure this out. Hope it helps anyone has the same questions.

And there is definitely something needed in its Python implementation to make it more elegant.

Comment: Nice answer.  Agreed, the lambda solution is great for simple filters if a little less than elegant.  To help clarify the lambda, here is my definition that might help with a detailed implementation:
` '()': lambda : lambda record: record.levelno != logging.ERROR,`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [loguru](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru) as logging package.
you can easily add a handler for your logger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that's not what I need. I want to understand how python logger filter works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because it is a bug or the docs are not correct.

In either case, I opened a ticket with the python folks here: https://bugs.python.org/issue41906

### Workaround

If you return a function that returns a function things will work fine.

For example:

```
def no_error_logs():
    """
    :return: function that returns 0 if log should show, 1 if not
    """
    return lambda param: 1 if param.levelno < logging.ERROR else 0
```

Then

```
    "filters": {
        "myfilter": {
            "()": no_error_logs,
        }
    },
```

Note: Your filter function returns true/false.

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter):
Filter functions are answering the question:

> Is the specified record to be logged? Returns zero for no, nonzero for yes.

So you would need to adjust your function accordingly.